# How to bypass the ros-gazebo rosmake/makefile magic?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Is there some documentation about how to build Gazebo for ROS after
trying to apply some patches? I do need bumper sensors, which are still
broken in 1.6.16 on Gazebo for ROS Fuerte.

The known patch was promised for 1.6.17, but this has not been released
(as of 02/Oct/2012)...

A normal rosbuild either does nothing, or first downloads and then
unpacks the "magic" tarballs with ROS-compatible Gazebo checkouts,
which in turn overwrites any patches applied to the source tree...

Is the following correct?

1. install ros-fuerte-simulator-gazebo package
2. remove any existing ROS_NOBUILD
3. rosmake --pre-clean
   (which downloads the magic tarball, unpacks, compiles everything)
4. cd to the actual gazebo source tree
5. edit some source files, apply patches, etc.
6. make
7. make install
8. cd to simulator_gazebo; touch ROS_NOBUILD

I am (trying to) use Gazebo on ROS Fuerte with the Shadow hand model.
The latest available release version is 1.6.12, with

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/37/how-to-bypass-the-ros-gazebo-rosmake/makefile-magic?/) by [Norman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/38/norman/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-10-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I'd recommend the following steps:

1. leave the debian installs (things inside `/opt/ros/fuerte/*` untouched) and work off of an overlay by following the steps below.  If you have already changed files inside of `/opt/ros/fuerte/*`, you might want to consider reinstalling affected packages by

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ros-fuerte-simulator-gazebo
```

1. create a workspace directory and cd into it

```
     mkdir ~/workspace
     cd ~/workspace
```

1. checkout [simulator_gazebo](http://ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo) stack.

```
    svn co https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/simulator_gazebo/branches/simulator_gazebo-1.6 simulator_gazebo
```

1. let ros know you want to use this stack instead of the one inside `/opt/ros/fuerte/...` and refresh rospack

```
    export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=~/workspace:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
    rospack profile
```

1. build `simulator_gazebo`.  Note that gazebo is pulled in from mercurial repo and built (see [Makefile.gazebo.hg](https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/simulator_gazebo/branches/simulator_gazebo-1.6/gazebo/Makefile.gazebo.hg)).

```
    rosmake simulator_gazebo
```

1. to make changes to gazebo, go inside the mercurial checkout inside `simulator_gazebo/gazebo/build/gazebo-hg/`.

---

Note that above is compiled against a ''fuerte''-branch inside of gazebo repository, it's a snapshot back at revision gazebo-1.0.2.  I've been testing it with gazebo-1.2.0 release candidate, if you want to test that branch out, get the sdf_1.2 branch

```
svn co https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/simulator_gazebo/branches/sdf_1.2 simulator_gazebo
```

But this is not yet completely stable.  And to run pr2 simulation, you might also want to checkout pr2_common along with it due to changes in SDF:

```
svn co https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/stacks/pr2_common/branches/sdf_1.2 pr2_common
```

as well as pr2_simulator

```
svn co https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/stacks/pr2_simulator/trunk pr2_simulator
```

into your workspace.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) with karma: 1873 on 2012-10-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0